# What's the meaning of stuttering in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> His correspondence online has been honest, full of his **stuttering**
> sincerity.

Does the adjective "stuttering" here mean "speaking with difficulty"? stammering?

Here's the full passage:
https://www.bookreporter.com/reviews/luster/excerpt

Comment: Link is behind a paywall.

Comment: @m_a_s, inserted a new link.

Answer (score 1):

I think the implication here is that, because he is not a good writer, he is not able to write a convincing lie — and so what he writes is clearly honest.

There is some evidence that this is an expression that has some currency. I've found:

> The best track by far on this album comes early, with a reworking of Skip James' "I'm So Glad." It is a spirited rendition, infused with a spluttering sincerity and ramshackle guitar work.

The suggestion in this quote is that the unskilled guitar playing is full of honest "spirit".

or

> He, Oscar Wilde, reduced to stuttering sincerity, said: 'This. This. This, then, is Utica.'

Oscar Wilde was a famous wit, and very skilled with words (and probably a very good lier) but is here unable to think of a clever lie, and has to stutter out the truth.

Answer (score 0):

Stuttering does not always refer to speech.  For example it could simply indicate a lack of fluency (similar to a sputtering engine).  But in this context, it is implied that sincerity comes in waves, as it would from someone who is exited---offering sincerity in frequent, perhaps short, bursts.